# Is postgresql sequence next val consist with insert order?

Tags: postgresql

Given an table with `id bigint default next_val('foo_sequence')`

Can I assume the order of `id` consisting with the insert order ?

I mean the later inserted `id` is always greater then earlier inserted ids.

I am trying to calculate and save an increment continuous number of row,

Here is how I did

```
SELECT count(*) as seq_no from foo where id < some_id;
// get the seq no

UPDATE foo SET seq_no = seq_no_above + 1 WHERE id = some_id;
```

But it sometimes give duplicate `seq_no` value, 
if the id consists with insert order, it should not have duplicate value.

Comment: Since the ID is assigned when the row is created, yes. It clearly would require that they be consistent with insert order. Why would you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @KenWhite I have  update my reason

Comment: You should not be calculating your own IDs. The server does that, and it does it much better than you possibly can.

Comment: @KenWhite Did you mean `row_number` ? I know but just wonder why duplicate values will appear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the simplest and purest sense, yes.  It depends what you mean by "earlier" and "later", though, as you have to consider opening the transaction and closing the transaction.  If a transaction has not been committed, then theoretically a record could show up later with an earlier ID.

The IDs are allocated when the insert happens, but the records will not show up until the records are committed.  So if commit order is different, you may see some strange behavior depending on how strict your use case is.

I.e.

```
Open Transaction A
Insert records 1,2

Open Transaction B
Insert records 3,4
Close transaction B

Select * (get 3,4)

Close transaction A

Select * (get 1,2,3,4)
```

You also have to worry about caching on whether you consider them to be sequential.  From the (very good) [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html):

> Furthermore, although multiple sessions are guaranteed to allocate
>   distinct sequence values, the values might be generated out of
>   sequence when all the sessions are considered. For example, with a
>   cache setting of 10, session A might reserve values 1..10 and return
>   nextval=1, then session B might reserve values 11..20 and return
>   nextval=11 before session A has generated nextval=2. Thus, with a
>   cache setting of one it is safe to assume that nextval values are
>   generated sequentially; with a cache setting greater than one you
>   should only assume that the nextval values are all distinct, not that
>   they are generated purely sequentially. Also, last_value will reflect
>   the latest value reserved by any session, whether or not it has yet
>   been returned by nextval.

One last caveat is someone with appropriate privileges can always reset the sequence to a different value, which obviously would throw a wrench into things.

**EDIT:**

To address your use case above, you definitely want to use sequences (and likely add NOT NULL / PRIMARY KEY constraints as well, to ensure uniqueness).  In pgAdmin, at least, you can do all of this by setting data type `serial`. Though I have mentioned caveats, for 99% of practical purposes, you get uniqueness and sequential ordering (hence *sequences*) the way that you want.

In any case, we would need to see example data to confirm why you are seeing duplication ([how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  I presume the duplication you are seeing is in `seq_no` and not `id`, which illustrates that the problem is your query.  If duplication is in `id`, then you have other problems, and that would explain duplication in `seq_no`.

Sequences are much better for transactional definition in the data (they take care of uniqueness for you, perform well in concurrency, and do not cause duplication... plus you get sequential ordering for the most part).  For unique keys, they are best used with `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraints.

But if you need a perfect increment, it is better to do something like the below:

```
select *, row_number() over (order by value) as id
from foo
;
```

Postgres [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) are very powerful, but are definitely not the standard to use for inserting data with sequential keys.  They are more useful for reporting, analysis, and complex queries after the fact.

Comment: `row_number`  is related to the query result, that is not actually what I need.